# how to change key of filter from Admin-on-rest framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, admin-on-rest

I use `<Autocomplete>` component in [Admin-on-rest](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/).

```
<ReferenceInput label="Media" reference="Media" source="media_id" allowEmpty>
    <AutocompleteInput source="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

If I type something in input, my rest-client get params with:

```
filter:{q: "1"}
```

I want replace q on name,  to be the same as my source. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize default behavious of `{ q: [searchText] }` using `filterToQuery` `prop`.

```
<ReferenceInput
     label="Media" 
     reference="Media" 
     source="media_id" 
     allowEmpty
     filterToQuery={searchText => ({ title: searchText })}>
    <AutocompleteInput source="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

You can change `title` here at `{ title: searchText }` to whatever you want to send to server.

Documentation: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#referenceinput

Search for `filterToQuery` in above link.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle that in a [custom `restClient`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client). As you can see in the documentation, it will receive the query type (in this case, `GET_LIST`), the `resource` so you get the name and the `params` object with `filter`. Thus, you can build another object from this filter however you like before sending it to your backend.